# sf::Http::sendRequest never returns

Tags: c++, http, sfml

I've written a simple web service using [`pistache`](http://pistache.io/). I'm seding requests to it using [`sf::Http`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.1/classsf_1_1Http.php) and [`sf::Http::Request`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.1/classsf_1_1Http_1_1Request.php) classes. However, call of `sf::Http::sendRequest` never returns, even though I specified a 250 ms timeout. The thing happens only with requests to my website. If I send `GET` request to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) the method returns correct response quite quickly.

Here's the client-side code sample:

```
sf::Http http("http://192.168.1.10", 8080);
sf::Http::Request request("/highscores", sf::Http::Request::Method::Get);
request.setHttpVersion(1, 1);
//the call below never returns
auto response = http.sendRequest(request, sf::seconds(0.25f));
std::cout << response.getBody();
```

The service response seems correct in browser and in curl:

```
$ curl -v 192.168.1.10:8080/highscores
*   Trying 192.168.1.10...
* Connected to 192.168.1.10 (192.168.1.10) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /highscores HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.1.10:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Content-Length: 2
< 
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.1.10 left intact
[]%
```

Using `strace` on my application shows that it sends correct request and even at some point it receives the correct response:

```
$ strace -s 192 ./sfmlApplication
...
sendto(20, "GET /highscores HTTP/1.1\r\nconnection: close\r\ncontent-length: 0\r\ncontent-type: application/json\r\nfrom: user@sfml-dev.org\r\nhost: 192.168.1.10\r\nuser-agent: libsfml-network/2.x\r\n\r\n", 176, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 176
recvfrom(20, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\nContent-Length: 2\r\n\r\n[]", 1024, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = 96
recvfrom(20,
```

These are the last lines from `strace` output, after `recvfrom(20,` the program stops responding and has to be killed.

And the top of stack trace of blocked operation is:

```
recv() at 0x7ffff7bcd10f    
sf::TcpSocket::receive() at 0x7ffff77b12c0  
sf::Http::sendRequest() at 0x7ffff77ad5ed
```

SFML Version: 2.3.2

System: Fedora 4.8.4-200.fc24.x86_64

**Any ideas why the `sf::Http::sendRequest` method call never returns?**

Comment: Run your SFML app in a debugger and either break before sending the request and then step into it or break the application when it seems to be stuck, then report back the call trace. What SFML version are you using?

Comment: @Lukas `strace` somehow shows which call blocks but, of course, I edited the post and pasted the stack trace as well. SFML 2.3.2 (from Fedora repositories).